# Github pull requests and file exclusion

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine, pull-request

I'm working on a Unity3D project with a small team, and Pull Requests are a nightmare. Every meta file is included in the pull request when all I want reviewed are the .cs files. The .meta files obviously need to be included in the commit, so is there a way to have Pull Requests be for specified files? If not, is there any way to have the Pull Request process slightly more organized? It's not bad as it is, but when dealing with 100+ meta files each commit it's really easy for a reviewer to miss a file completely.

EDIT: I should say that I've spent a ton of time researching code review alternatives and it's a lot of extra effort (or cost) for just hiding some files. It doesn't help that google searching for this question results in mostly .gitignore questions, which doesn't help.

EDIT 2: These are not the meta files located in Library. These are the meta files generated from setting the Unity editor's revision settings.

Comment: Are these the meta files in the `Library` directory (which can be ignored) or the meta files specific to the scripts you mention?

Comment: @jozzas These are the meta files located in Assets/. They are the textual representation of Unity so that git can handle revisions and whatnot. They're 100% vital and without them there is no Unity "merging" as it is normally binary. So unfortunately they cannot just be ignored. And I don't believe there are meta files for the scripts, just the Assets (excluding the scripts).

Answer (score 1):

The meta files are essential. But having a 100 of them change in a commit is strange. Checklist of potential problems:

1. Is everyone using the same unity3d version? They should use the same version number (ie. unity 4.5.2 OSX and 4.5.2 Win should work together, but if someone is using 4.3.4 there will be issues)
2. Is Edit->Project Settings->Editor->Version control set to visible and asset serialization to text? They should.
3. What is the diff of a typical change? A meta file for `.cs` doesn't change with it's contents.
4. What are the contents of your `.gitignore`? A good one Is:

`/.gitignore`:

```
/Assembly*
/obj
/Library
/Temp
/*.sln
/*.userprefs
.DS_Store
```

Comment: If it's open source, please post your github project url

Comment: My Unity settings aren't the issue and 100 files in a commit isn't that strange. You have to remember that the meta files represent every aspect of the project that would normally be in binary. So, if I change a component attribute, that meta file will change. So on a large commit where 3D components have been moved, added, deleted and code written around them then there will be a lot of associative meta files. This is why I'm interested in excluding the meta files in the pull request, and not blocking them in other ways. And there's actually all that and more in my .gitignore. :)

Comment: From your question it looked like you had lots of changes in .cs related meta files and hundreds of changes on those is strange (maybe except adding a library, but that is not often). Back to blocking meta files: *don't*. You'll loose almost everything that someone had setup in the inspector: texture params, model params, links to prefabs and scripts etc. The meta files are there for a reason.

Comment: I'm not wanting to "block" them. My question is how to filter them out in the Github Pull Request. It has nothing to do with how Unity handles it.